# Spotfire Custom Expressions - Fill null values with previous values

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I am using a dataset that has daily data joined with another data set (well tests) that has 1-3 entries a month per location. I want to calculate a ratio of the daily data to the well tests but then use that ratio until a new test is recorded and replace that ratio.

I've tried several different combinations of functions using Last() with over and intersects but am unsuccessful. The only way I have been able to get it to work is using LastValidBefore() and FirstValidAfter() but only when there is a single well in the dataset.

Couldn't figure out how to post the table but I put them in the following google sheet... [Sample data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DA5z4-oFtbOYQB-6Qo1r3RrFjU3LS0_XVqOn89v7U6k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Pls, give access to your spreadsheet

Comment: I did it. sorry I suck with google sheets

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
={"Oil Ratio";arrayformula(if(D2:D="",,D2:D/C2:C))}
```

in F1 in your spreadsheet